# How to connect to an HTTPS API utilizing HTTP Basic Auth using Python Requests?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, basic-authentication

I'd like to utilize the [Guesty API](https://guestyorg.github.io/guesty-api/#introduction) via Python Requests, and it requires requests to be made over HTTPS and authenticated via HTTP Basic Auth (instructions below).

I've tried utilizing Python Requests and HTTPBasicAuth, which you can see below, but I get a Response [404].

How can I connect to the Guesty API using Python Requests?

> To use the Guesty API, you’ll need a private API key that is linked to
>   your account. You can generate one here
>
> Be sure to keep this API key private. All API requests must be made
>   over HTTPS and are authenticated via HTTP Basic Auth. Use your API key
>   as the username and secret as the password.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

print requests.get("https://superhostuser.herokuapp.com/api/v2/", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api, secret))
```

The documentation also states:

> The default base URL for Guesty API is:
>   https://superhostuser.herokuapp.com/api/v2/
>
> Note: for security reasons, all Guesty APIs are served over HTTPS
>   only.

Comment: Are you sure the root URL is a valid endpoint ? A 404 response is probably not related with authentication.

Comment: Well in the documentation, it states "The default base URL for Guesty API is:  https://superhostuser.herokuapp.com/api/v2/". See documentation here: https://guestyorg.github.io/guesty-api

Comment: Yes, but I can't find what it is supposed to return. Have you tried https://superhostuser.herokuapp.com/api/v2/me ?

Comment: Actually good call. I get response 200 with the following: https://superhostuser.herokuapp.com/api/v2/search. Should I delete this question or keep open?